# mariadb json query to get parent keys of specific child value

Tags: json, mariadb

I got clients with contracts stored in json format in a mariadb database (10.3.21).

The parent keys are id's of contract types, cb = checkbox if contract is checked (1) or not (0), p & pt are price related and not really relevant for my question.

The simplified json format is structured as follows:

```
{
    "1": {
        "cb": "0",
        "p": "1",
        "pt": "m"
    },
    "2": {
        "cb": "1",
        "p": "395",
        "pt": "y"
    },
    "3": {
        "cb": "0",
        "p": "",
        "pt": "m"
    },
    "7": {
        "cb": "1",
        "p": "120",
        "pt": "m"
    }
}
```

I can query the database so I can get results of all the companies that have a specific contract type.

```
SELECT
       `id`
     , `company`
FROM
       `db`.`clients`
WHERE
       JSON_VALUE(`contracts`, '$.2.cb')=1
```

But I want to query json so I get an array of parent keys where child key cb = 1. 
So it would give `["2","7"]` as result for this json.

I thought something in the line of following, but that's not working. 
Getting an empty result set instead of what I hoped for.

```
SELECT
       `id`
     , `company`
     , JSON_QUERY(`contracts`, '$') AS `contracttypes`
FROM
       `db`.`clients`
WHERE
       JSON_VALUE(`contracts`, '$.%.cb')=1
```

Can't find (yet) if wildcards in paths are possible and if so what the syntax should be, so I get the results I want.

**Alternative approach**

Tried alternative approach with better results, but not there yet.

```
SELECT
       `id`
     , `company`
     , json_search(`contracts`,'all','1') AS `contracttypes`
FROM
       `db`.`clients`
```

Results: `["$.1.p", "$.2.cb", "$.7.cb"]`
The keys of the cb items are what I want, but the first key due to the p item is not wanted.

Trying to do `json_search` on key with value like following give null result.

```
json_search(`contracts`,'all','"cb":"1"')

/* or with curlies */

json_search(`contracts`,'all','{"cb":"1"}')
```

Comment: Not tried yet, but maybe I should do a regular expression on top of the alternative approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    JSON_SEARCH(@`json`, 'all', '1', NULL, '$**.cb'),
    '[$.]|[.cb]',
    SPACE(0)
  ) `json_result`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=40775bbc03c72636fabbb810c14f639e).

Comment: When posting my comment, I was out of time to look at the regular expression myself. Thank you for taking care of this for me!

Comment: Oh and you got the wildcard working in the json function. Cool!